# mod rewrite /iran/iran/ to /iran/

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to do a simple re write

from

`http://www.example.com/iran/iran/province/Yazd`

to

`http://www.example.com/iran/province/Yazd`

This is a codeigniter app that i have put in 'iran' folder.  The class name is Iran that is why there are 2 'iran' after each other.
I've managed to remove my codeigniter 'index.php' from the url with rewrite

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ iran/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you use that rule in the .htaccess file in your document root. If so, try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^iran/(iran/.*) /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/iran/index\.php
RewriteRule ^iran/(.*) iran/index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The first is to redirect `/iran/iran/`*`foo`* externally to `/iran/`*`foo`*. And the second is to pass any request of `/iran/`*`foo`* internally to `/iran/index.php?/iran/`*`foo`*.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a Rewritebase to the .htaccess in your iran folder.

```
RewriteBase   /iran
```

Then replace your rewrite to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

---

Original Answer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/iran/iran/(.*)$ /iran/$1 [L]
```

Comment: If it's in a .htaccess file then replace "^/" with "^"